# careers profile does not handle renaming of GitHub repos properly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, github

After renaming a project on GitHub the following happens:

After hitting update in my profile (`/import/github/{userid}`) I will see the old(-named) repository alongside the newer version and need to manually remove the old one.

I am aware that this is sort of an edge-case and also that renaming GitHub-repos will always come with a truckload of pain, but maybe this is an easy fix for you.

Comment: Looking into this now, will get back later today!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We now deal with this gracefully but only for GitHub repos. They're the only ones that have a unique identifier other than the URL.

This will work immediately with new repos that you subsequently rename and will eventually be propagated across older ones too, although that will take upto two weeks to complete (GitHub throttles requests so we can't do it any faster than that)!

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!